# Unable to install Visual Studio Desktop development with C++ using powershel

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I'm trying to use Powershell to update an instance of Visual Studio Professional with the `Desktop development with C++`. I have read the following pages

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-professional?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true

As a result I created the following powershell command:

```
$VSVersion = Get-CimInstance MSFT_VSInstance | Select-Object -First 1

if ($VSVersion) {
    $InstallationPath = $VSVersion.InstallLocation

    Write-Host "Updating $($VSVersion.Caption) ..."

    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
     Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" `
    -ArgumentList "update --passive --norestart 
    --productId Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop 
    --installpath $($InstallationPath) 
    --add Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SecurityIssueAnalysis
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.TSServer
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Vcpkg
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22000
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake"
    
    Write-Host "$($VSVersion.Caption) successfully updated"
}
```

Unfortunately, although the scripts were completed correctly, if I open the Visual Studio Installer, it seems that the package was not installed.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to install as Admin.  PS does automatically run As Admin.  So start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Also make sure you install for All users.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm executing the PS as Admin. Apparently everything is ok. Is there something to specify `for All users`?

Comment: Try to separate the arguments contained in `-ArgumentList` by space only. Newlines might not be supported. You could store them in an array variable and pass that to `-ArgumentList`, which automatically joins them by space.

Comment: Also, the `InstallationPath` variable must be quoted: `--installpath \`"$InstallationPath\`"`